# Returning Map from JDBC template execution

Tags: java, jdbctemplate

```
public List<Employee> getEmployeeDetails() {
    return jdbcTemplate.query(GET_EMPLOYEE_SQL, new RowMapper<Employee>() {
        @Override
        public Employee mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            Employee employee = new Employee();
            employee.setCode(rs.getBigDecimal("cd"));
            employee.setAddress(rs.getString("address"));
            employee.setContactNo((rs.getString("contactNo")));

            return employee;
        }
    });
}
```

what I need to do from above method its returning List but I need to return

```
Map<BigDecimal, List<Employee>> employeeMap = new HashMap<>();

while doing that getting exception
```

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Map<BigDecimal, Employee>> to
> Map<BigDecimal, Employee>

Please find below code

```
public Map<BigDecimal, Employee> getEmployeeDetails() {
Map<BigDecimal, Employee> employeeMap = new HashMap<>();

    return jdbcTemplate.query(GET_EMPLOYEE_SQL, new RowMapper<Map<String, Employee>>() {
        @Override
        public Map<BigDecimal, Employee> mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            Employee employee = new Employee();
            employee.setCode(rs.getBigDecimal("cd"));
            employee.setAddress(rs.getString("address"));
            employee.setContactNo((rs.getString("contactNo")));

            employeeMap.put(rs.getBigDecimal("cd"), employee);

            return employeeMap;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things,

1. Don't return the query statement, return `employeeMap` in your getEmployeeDetails() method.
2. For your expectations from query, you have to use `ResultSetExtractor` not `RowMapper` with RowMapper you are doing the operation for every row, hence it returns list always.

With `ResultSetExtractor` you can do something like

```
return template.query(GET_EMPLOYEE_SQL, new ResultSetExtractor<Map<BigDecimal, Employee>>() {
        @Override
        public Map<BigDecimal, Employee> extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
            Map<BigDecimal, Employee> employeeMap = new HashMap<>();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Employee employee = new Employee();
                employee.setCode(rs.getBigDecimal("cd"));
                employee.setAddress(rs.getString("address"));
                employee.setContactNo((rs.getString("contactNo")));
                employeeMap.put(rs.getBigDecimal("cd"), employee); 
            }
            return employeeMap;
        }
    });
```